# select a value in dropdown list from two database tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to edit the employees's information in a dropdown list, I have two database tables where there is a shared field : 
in table1, I have many fields and one of them is the employee **Position** which is a number. in table2 I have two fields: **EmpPos**(which is equal to **Position** in table1) and **PosName**.
Now, in the dropdown list, when I add a new employee I fill the list with **PosName** from table2 but store Position number in table1.
the problem is in the edit form, I print all employee's info from table1 in the form to edit them but I don't know how to select employee's **PosName** from its associated **Position** in the dropdown list
here is my code:

```
echo" <b>Position: </b>  <select name='Position' >";
    $sql="SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.Position = table2.EmpPos";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
         if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $PosName=$row["PosName"];
        $Id=$row['EmpPos'];
echo" <option name= '$PosName'  value='$PosName' ' . (($Id==$Position) ? 'selected'  : '') . '>$PosName</option>";
        }
        }
```

thanks

Comment: It seems unlikely that `id` would be equal to `position`.

Answer (score 0):

Write query to get all position from position table:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM positionTable order by position name asc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$Empquery = "Fetch all data related to that employee.";
echo" <b>Position: </b>  <select name='Position' >";
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $PosName=$row["PosName"];
    $Id=$row['EmpPos']; //it must emp's position id fetch from other query. 
    echo" <option name= '$PosName'  value='$PosName' ' . (($Id==$Position) ? 'selected'  : '') . '>$PosName</option>";
    }
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: the problem is only with the dropdown list values, I want the stored value to be selected by default once I open the edit form

Comment: `(($Id==$Position) ? 'selected'  : '')` this part show the value selected if you add $id= employee position id $ $position = position id

Comment: print the value of `$Id` & `$Position` it will help you to debug